# How to solve RuntimeException: TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert 1:class java.lang.String to Long for column?

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I am developing simple web application with play framework with scala and storing databse in mysql  and i am getting error

[image: Exception]

what am i doing :

- when user enter values and after storing i am redirecting user to page that show all entries present in the database
- values are getting stored but it give exception at time of redirecting to page

**`models/Keyword.scala`**

```
case class Keyword(blog: String,cat: String,word: String,count: Long, summaryId: String)

object Keyword {


  val keyw = {
    get[String]("keyword.blog")~
    get[String]("keyword.cat")~
    get[String]("keyword.word")~
  get[Long]("keyword.count") ~ 
  get[String]("keyword.summaryId") map {
    case blog~cat~word~count~summaryId => Keyword(blog,cat,word,count, summaryId)
  }
}

  def all(): List[Keyword] = DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
  SQL("select * from keyword").as(Keyword.keyw *)
}


def create(key: Keyword){DB.withConnection{implicit c=> 
  SQL("insert into keyword values({blog}, {cat}, {word},{count},{summaryId})").on('blog->key.blog,
      'cat -> key.cat,
      'word-> key.word,
      'count-> key.count,
      'summaryId -> key.summaryId).executeUpdate()
}
}
```

**`controllers/Application.scala`**

```
object Application extends Controller {

  val ta:Form[Keyword] = Form(
          mapping(
    "blog" -> nonEmptyText,
    "cat" -> nonEmptyText,
    "word" -> nonEmptyText,
    "count"-> of[Long],
    "summaryId"-> nonEmptyText
  )(Keyword.apply)(Keyword.unapply)
  )

  def index = Action {
    Ok(html.index(ta));
  }
  def newTask=  Action { implicit request =>
  ta.bindFromRequest.fold(
    errors => BadRequest(html.index(errors)),
    keywo => {

      Keyword.create(keywo)
      Ok(views.html.data(Keyword.all()))
    }
  )
}
```

**- when i am using h2-database that time it is running**

**- when i am using MySQL that time it is giving exception**

Give me some idea to solve this issue!

Comment: Could it be that count is a string column in your MySQL database schema?

Comment: yes it's true it's `string` in  `Mysql` database but in `h2` it is `BIGINT` why ?

Comment: Because you have created the schema that way? Are you managing it with evolutions or by hand?

Comment: @ rahul do u mean Anorm Db as h2??

Answer (score 1):

Create an AnormExtension helper in app/helpers folder.  Call it AnormExtension.scala.  Code below:

```
object AnormExtension {

implicit def rowJavaLongToLong: Column[Long] = Column.nonNull { (value, meta) =>
  val MetaDataItem(qualified, nullable, clazz) = meta
    value match {
       case d: java.lang.Long => Right(d.longValue())
       case _ => Left(TypeDoesNotMatch("Cannot convert " + value + ":" + value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass + " to Long for column " + qualified))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would often get this error when trying to do an INSERT with pgsql and anorm. I sovled it by using the Sql String parser. this may work for you... not 100% sure though:

```
 def all(): List[Keyword] = DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
  SQL("select * from keyword").as(Keyword.keyw *).execute(SqlParser.scalar[String].singleOpt)
}
```